# Webkit (Chrome & Safari) leaves artefact after overflow: visible to hidden

Tags: html, css, webkit

I'm trying to get a full size image appear when you hover over the thumbnail using overlays and overflow:hidden & visible.

It works fine in Firefox and IE but Chrome & Safari leave a mess. You can see it here
[Webkit artefact](http://www.galadai.com/artefacts.html)

This is the CSS I'm using:

```
.img-thumb
{
    position:relative;
    height:60px;
    width:60px;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:5px;
    font-family:Comic Sans MS, cursive, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
}
.img-full
{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
.img-thumb:hover .img-full
{
    display:block;
    z-index:10;
}
.img-thumb:hover
{
    overflow:visible;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML (or better yet, a JSFiddle)? Your link doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Link works for me and I can confirm artifact is left on the background.

Comment: That's clearly a bug. Do you want to work it around, or wait it out?

Comment: Hmm... it doesn't happen if the result overflows the screen

Comment: I'd be interested in any workaround ideas

Answer (score 0):

The bug seems to be dependent on `position: absolute` (i've tried it on `position: relative`, and bug appears as well.) for `.img-full`.

Of course, making it `position: static` (or simply removing the `position: absolute`) would make the `overflow: hidden` work properly, but you'd have the problem of positioning your `.img-full`.

Comment: That works right but, as you say, I lose the ability to position over the thumbnail

Answer (score 0):

The only option I see here (as partial workaround) is to assign a proper height to hovered img-thumb container (which allows browser to know exactly what box to clear up on mouse out).

```
.img-thumb:hover
{
    overflow:visible;
    height: 500px; /* when added clears the artefacts - but total height of hover must be known as set here and shall not change */
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/YqSVP/ as a working example to see the fix - will be sufficient only if hover height is known and can be fixed to some value inside css.

Looks to me like webkit is optimizing too much the cleanup procedure of box mouse out repaining and ignores the absolute positioned children when clearing up the box - though the display on hover works just fine (i'd bet this is some bug in webkit).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but resolved using JS/jQuery:

E.g.:

```
$(".img-thumb").hover(
  function () {
    $(".img-thumb > .img-full").show();
  },
  function () {
    $(".img-thumb > .img-full").fadeOut(1);
  }
);
```

fadeOut(1) make the element fading in 1ms, so user cant note the effect.